# Can't Import properties after integrating spring-batch-admin into existed spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-batch, spring-batch-admin

I have worked on a project using spring-batch and spring-boot.

I followed the exact rules how to integrate it by:
1. removing all @EnableBatchProcessing
2. adding ServletConfiguration and WebappConfiguration (and also import them using

```
@Import({ ServletConfiguration.class, WebappConfiguration.class })
```

3. add props:

   batch-mysql.properties

   business-schema-mysql

and modified application.properties with:

```
server.servletPath=/*
spring.freemarker.checkTemplateLocation=false
ENVIRONMENT=mysql
```

Now here is the side effect. My app is using an applicationContext .xml in addition to it's java config.

that applicationContext has some place holders:

```
  <context:property-placeholder
            location="file:///etc/location/services/myapp.properties"/>


    <bean name="configuration" class="com.mycompany.commons.configuration.factory.BeanAwareConfigurationFactory">

        <property name="serviceId" value="${serviceId}"/>
       ...
    </bean>
```

As soon as I integrated `spring-batch-admin` I got this error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'serviceId' in string value "${serviceId}"
    at 
...
```

I tried @PropertySource to import it, but it didn't work:

```
  @PropertySource("file:///etc/location/services/myapp.properties")
    public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
            System.out.printf("Started processor service app");
        }
```

As soon as I removed `spring-batch-admin` from my `spring-boot` project I manage to attach those props.

Any idea how to overcome this?

Comment: Did you find out a solution? I'm having the same problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can override `spring-batch-admin`default context loading configuration. In `src/main/resources/META-INF/spring/batch/override/manager/` you can place `env-context.xml` file with configuration of resources which need to be loaded.

Here is [spring batch admin](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch-admin/blob/master/spring-batch-admin-manager/src/main/resources/META-INF/spring/batch/bootstrap/manager/env-context.xml) one which can be used as starting point so you can do something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

    <!--  Use this to set additional properties on beans at run time -->
    <bean id="placeholderProperties" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="locations">
            <list>
                <value>classpath:/org/springframework/batch/admin/bootstrap/batch.properties</value>
                <value>classpath:batch-default.properties</value>
                <value>classpath:batch-${ENVIRONMENT:hsql}.properties</value>
                <!-- this line you can add-->
                <value>file:///etc/location/services/myapp.properties</value>  
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="systemPropertiesModeName" value="SYSTEM_PROPERTIES_MODE_OVERRIDE" />
        <property name="ignoreResourceNotFound" value="true" />
        <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="false" />
        <property name="order" value="1" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

Comment: fixed. however new error. open new question at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29207484/spring-batch-and-spring-batch-integration-throwing-message-exception

Comment: I wanted to mention that in my answer, we had same setup (spring boot + spring batch + spring batch admin) and it resulted in more pain than solution so we separated that in two apps on same DB, spring batch admin is used only for monitoring and we have spring batch app doing jobs.

Comment: Yes. I find myself workaround this alot. not sure if I should separate now my app into 2 services

Comment: The thing you will loose is ability to start manually jobs from spring batch admin since it is not reading jobs from DB, but from configuration file and configuration file would be in different app, just as suggestion if you go that road but we use it for monitoring only so that is ok with us

Comment: I am having another exception: Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.http.converter.json.Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder.modulesToInstall([Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/databind/Module;)Lorg/springframework/http/converter/json/Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder;
  any idea?

Comment: Maybe spring batch admin is using object mapper which is 1.x and you added fasterxml which is 2.x and they are colliding?

Comment: I didnt add any fastexml of my own.. mybe it comes from somewhere else?

Comment: Seems like spring-batch integration has higher version after fixing this I got another exception but I am giving up on this project. the integration is too hard btw them.  No qualifying bean of type [com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper]..expected single matching bean but found 3: jacksonMapper,objectMapper,_halObjectMapper... anyway I give up

Answer (score 2):

I forked the github project and I added the fix to prevent the placeholder error. You can get the new code here: https://github.com/vesperaba/spring-batch-admin-spring-boot.

The issue was SpringBatch has it's own PropertyPlaceholder and you have to overwrite it but to do that you have to manually import some files in order to avoid the one define it.

Here you can find the new conf: https://github.com/vesperaba/spring-batch-admin-spring-boot/blob/master/src/main/java/de/codecentric/batch/config/MainV2Configuration.java