# Spring batch admin and Spring batch integration throwing MessagingException

Tags: spring, spring-batch, spring-batch-admin

Following the solution of my prev question at: [cant import resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29195981/cant-import-properties-after-integrating-spring-batch-admin-into-existed-spring/29196768#29196768)

I managed finally to overcome the properties configuration after trying to integrate spring-batch-admin

However now I get different error:

..

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/integration/MessagingException
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2615)
```

This is my gradle script:

```
dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.batch:spring-batch-integration:3.0.1.RELEASE')
    compile("org.springframework.batch:spring-batch-admin-manager:1.3.1.RELEASE"){
        exclude module: 'slf4j-log4j12'
        exclude module: 'slf4j-api'
    }
compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-batch:1.2.2.RELEASE
..
```

So I guess I am having some version collisions between the two.

This already consumed long time for me. any idea if there easy solution to over come before giving up on this?

Thanks,
ray.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are forced to use `spring-batch-admin:2.0.0.M1` with Spring Boot.

Exactly the `2.0` version is based on the Spring Framework 4.1 and Spring Integration 4.1.

Otherwise it won't work, because `1.3.1` requires SF 3.2 and SI 3.0

Comment: After fixing this I got another exception: Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.http.converter.json.Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder.modulesToInstall([Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/databind/Module;)Lorg/springframework/http/converter/json/Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder;

Comment: Looks like a new SO question with comprehensive StackTrace to determine the guilty guy

Comment: I actually doubt if I should keep continue with this. already consumed lots of time.